# Blank screen on other devices for Google Maps API other than my test device

Tags: java, android, android-activity, google-maps-api-3, android-manifest

I am currently stuck with a problem that I cannot solve. I have developed and released an Android app in the Google Play Store. This app worked fine as it should and displayed a map of the Google Maps API for Android on my test device, a Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime. I used this Device for testing purposes in different networks (WIFI´s) at different locations. The map always showed the actual markers and location as it should. Google released the app in the Google Play Store. However, at least two completely differently located users in Germany that have downloaded and installed the app now tell me that they get a blank screen where the map should be at completely different places, several hundred kilometers distance from each other, and don´t see their actual location on the map, as it should be. How is that possible? Why was my test device in different locations and in different networks always displaying the actual location with a marker on a map correctly, and why do other users who downloaded the app don´t see their actual location? What might be the reasons for that? The rest of the app is working as it should. The app is not crashing. Any hints or help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Release APK should use different signed Google Maps API Key. 
Sign your release APK first and use it to get your Google Maps API Key.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed my isssue...was not aware of that